# Answers need their personal space in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I personally think the bold "Answer:" text is a little hard to pick up on (I've mistakenly clicked an answer thinking it was a question a few times now), but that aside, there should at least be a space between it and the start of the post contents:

[image: answer indicator with missing space]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thiswillbefixedinthenextbuild.