# Searching for answers on Android App?

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

I was looking at my Stack Overflow profile on the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), tapped one of the tags, and was greeted with this:

> [image: Search for "user:1340389 [python-internals]" with no results.]

But when I put that search into the website, I get [three results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1340389+%5Bpython-internals%5D) which are all answers. Maybe I've misdiagnosed the issue, but it looks like the search box does not allow searching for answers.

Is there a reason for this restriction? Even if there is a good reason, **can we either make tapping a tag work correctly, or disable it entirely?**

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason for this restriction?

Yes, in a sense. It's due to the limitation of [current Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs), which SE Android app is heavily using for its functionalities, having endpoints only to search questions:

> **Search**
>
> - /search - Search the site for *questions* meeting certain criteria.
> - /search/advanced - Search the site for *questions* using most of the on-site search options.
> - /similar - Search the site based on similarity to a (*question's*) title.
> - /search/excerpts - Searches a site (with parameters all related to *question's properties*).

The SE Android app itself is using [/search/excerpts](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search).

Until there's a modification to SE API <sup>or doing what the iOS app seems to have done</sup>, it's *impossible* to search for answers, even by forcing *is:answer* keyword.

<sup>Unrelated note: as of v1.0.85, the current text hint on the search box is "*Search Questions...*", so I can't really blame that it doesn't search for answers...</sup>

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do we know what the iOS app "seems to have done"?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I don't have any idea since I don't have iOS devices/can't test or experiment with the app, but based on [the title of a minor bug on iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220343/answers-need-their-personal-space-in-search-results), I assume it can search for answers.